# How can I do a line break (line continuation) in Elixir?

Tags: syntax, elixir

In Python, for example, one can break line with '\' character (yeah, necessary evil). Is it possible to break lines in Elixir?

Comment: "\" is also available in Elixir when you don't want to rely on a specific operator terminating or not.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Elixir is not as whitespace-sensitive as Python, so you can do things like:

```
a =
  2 + 4 +
 3
# a is bound to 9
```

If you want to break strings, probably your best shot is to concatenate one string per line:

```
"this is a very long string that " <>
  "spans multiple lines because man, " <>
  "is it long"
```

Comment: In reference to that last point, @whatyouhide, see also heredocs.  Heredocs seem a much better approach for the multiline string case. See this: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/module-attributes.html

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci yes but they introduce newlines that you may not want :). They're super useful when writing a prose-like text for example.

Answer (score 8):

Based on [Jose Valim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588267/jos%C3%A9-valim) comment.

```
iex(1)> "hello\
...(1)> world"
"helloworld"
iex(2)>
```